# Fading image after load from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I would like to fade in the images after the images have loaded after the ajax call.
This way the fade actually happens instead of the user watching the image load.

May someone help me out?

Here's the JS snippet:

```
success: function(data){
    $('.main-content').load(function() {
      $(data).hide().prependTo('.main-content').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    return false;
},
```

Data will come in from php echoing something like this:

```
<div class='left-col-box'>
  <div class='album_image'>
    <div class='image_settings'>
      <button class='delete_button' id='11'>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <img src='/includes/thumber.php?file=../img/$next_id.$ext&width=218&height=218' />
  </div>
</div>
```

If 2 images were uploaded, there can be 2 left-col-box strings for 2 loaded boxes.
I would like the image to be loaded before the `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 loader.show()  //show some loading image
 $('img',data).load(function(){
      loader.hide //hide loader once img is loaded
          $(data).prependTo('.main-content');
       }
```

Comment: i was about to delete my answer ,i thought what i understood from you question was wrong.:)

Comment: The thing is, if I did .fadeIn(500), it just loads regularly.  I can't even catch the fade whatsoever. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: So if I have .fadeIn(500), the image will load as if it didn't even wait for it to be loaded.  Also if I do .fadeIn(1000), the image loads fully, and then the background does some weird overlay opacity on the already loaded image.

Comment: show some loading image then hide it when image loaded this fadeIn and all is not needed

Answer (score 0):

If the `data` in the `success` callback is the generated HTML you will need to attach it first then hide it and than fading it in.

Not sure `$(data).hide()` works as expected as at that point `data` is not in the DOM yet.

Try the following (I don't think you need load):

```
success: function(data){
    $(data).prependTo('.main-content').find('div.album_image img').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
},
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/trLJ8/) - Loading image and slowly fading it in, using above code

---

That above DEMO useds the suggested code and prepends the generated HTML, then finds the image tag, hides it and then slowly fades it in.

Off course if you generate the `img` tag upfront hidden, for example with a `display: none` or similar then all you should need is:

```
$(data).prependTo('.main-content').find('div.album_image img').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Hmm. I like the simplicity of your code.  Does it guarantee that the images will be loaded though?  What if I had a huge image to be loaded?

Comment: @user1952509: Success should only be triggered if all the data is ready. If you are wondering about the size of the image for hiding and fading you can update the fiddle changing the width and height of the placeholder image to humongous values. I'm on my phone at the moment and can't check the fiddle right now, sorry.

Comment: Nvm. I found a fix.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1952509: tested it and changing the image in the fiddle to a huge image (4000x2000) and the fadein to 500 or 2000 works fine too.